# LoadFromDataTable With TableStyles creates an Error upon re-opening Excel Workbook

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml, export-to-excel, epplus

I've gone looking online for this solution and can't find anything that explains my problem.

I am using EPPLus for vb.net (using OfficeOpenXml) and my code looks something like this:

```
Dim Package As New ExcelPackage
Dim wks As ExcelWorksheet
Dim dt As DataTable

wks.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True, TableStyles.Medium9)

Dim SaveAs As New FileInfo([...somelocation.xlsx])
Package.SaveAs(SaveAs)
```

Now, when I run this, it works perfectly well and saves the .xlsx file as wanted / expected. HOWEVER, when I try and open it in Excel, I get an error saying:
**"Excel found unreadable content in... Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?"**

If I then click "Yes", It opens it perfectly fine and gives me an error report saying:
"Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content"
with lots of erros (one for each datatable loaded):
"Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)"

NOW... If I change the line of code from:

```
wks.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True, TableStyles.Medium9)
```

To:

```
wks.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)
```

Then everything work perfectly well with no errors...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ... Ok, I'm one step closer - turns out I found out that a few of the columns in my datatable are causing the issue... but i can't find out why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... So I figured out what MY problem was and I'm just putting it in here in case anyone is as stupid as I was...

In my case, I created the Datatable with custom columns names that were split up over 2 lines as follows:

```
dt.Columns.Add("First Line's Text" & vbCrLf & "Second Line")
```

The problem was the **vbCrLf** - I changed it to:

```
dt.Columns.Add("First Line's Text" & vbLf & "Second Line")
```

And the error went away :)

Hope this saves someone else all the annoyance I went through!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (at least the same symptoms) and my issue turned out to be because i had a ':' in my the DataTable.TableName.

I discovered that EPPlus uses the DataTable.TableName as the displayName in the table1.xml from the .xlsx file and that it does not support the ':' char.

I figured it out by comparing the corrupt output to the version that Excel has fixed.  You can look at the underlying structure of office documents by simply opening them as a .zip file (rename them from .xlsx to .zip) then you can look at the underlying files.  In my case Excel pointed me to the table1.xml file so it was easy to find.

I fixed the problem by simply replacing any ':' in my DataTable.TableName with an  '_'.

Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: I had a different problem again, the key was your suggestion to do a before and after comparison on the file in the zip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, both of my table names and column names are dynamic so there is potential for invalid characters. Here's the code that I stole from someone else that will replace all of those:

```
protected string ReplaceSpecialChars(string inputName)
    {
        char[] verbotten = new char[] { ' ', '/', '\'', '"', '\'', '@', '`', '#', '%', '>', '<', '!', '.', '[', ']', '*', '$', ';', ':', '?', '^', '{', '}', '+', '-', '=', '~', '\\' };

        int pos = -1;
        while ((pos = inputName.IndexOfAny(verbotten)) != -1)
            inputName = inputName.Substring(0, pos) + inputName.Substring(pos + 1);

        return inputName;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by my DataTable name. My solution was to add an extended property to the DataTable then call it on creation of the spreadsheet.

```
dataTable.ExtendedProperties.Add("Title",someText);
```

Then later

```
var tableTitle = sheet.Cells[range];
tableTitle.Merge = true;
tableTitle.Value = dataTable.ExtendedProperties["Title"];
```